# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. Partial<Class> undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, partial-classes, alertify

I searched a lot but couldn't find. My Codes as below.

I created one alertify Service but I get the following error: "`Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. Partial<Class> undefined ?`"

I don't understand why the code is detecting my index type as 'undefined'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare let alertify: any;

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertifyService {

  constructor() { }

  message(message: string, options: Partial<AlertifyOptions>) {
    alertify.set('notifier', 'position', options.position);
    alertify.set('notifier', 'delay', options.delay);
    alertify[options.messageType](message);

  }
}

export class AlertifyOptions {
  messageType: AlertifyMessageType = AlertifyMessageType.Success;
  position: AlertifyPositions = AlertifyPositions.BottomRightCenter;
  delay: number = 3;
  dismissOthers: boolean = false;
}
export enum AlertifyMessageType {
  Success = "success",
  Warning = "warning",
  Message = "message",
  Error = "error",
  Notifier = "notifier"
}

export enum AlertifyPositions {
  TopRight = "top-right",
  TopCenter = "top-center",
  Topleft = "top-left",
  BottomRight = "bottom-right",
  BottomRightCenter = "bottom-center",
  BottomRightBottom = "bottom-right"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pXOt.png)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr make sure you null check properties from a `Partial` type before trying to use them

---

When you use the `Partial` type in TypeScript, you effectively take an existing type and mark each property as optional. An optional type in TypeScript is for most intents and purposes equivalent to the key being capable of being `undefined`.

For example:

```
interface SomeObject {
    key1: string;
    key2: number;
}

type PartialSomeObject = Partial<SomeObject>
// equivalent to
interface PartialSomeObject {
    key1?: string;
    key2?: number;
}
// or
interface PartialSomeObject {
    key1: string | undefined;
    key2: number | undefined;
}
```

Because **all** keys are optional, in essence that means none of them are mandatory. A completely valid assignment of `PartialSomeObject` is as follows:

```
const somePartialObject: PartialSomeObject = {} // all optional keys are missing
```

---

Back to your example, you have the following:

```
message(message: string, options: Partial<AlertifyOptions>) {
  alertify.set('notifier', 'position', options.position);
  alertify.set('notifier', 'delay', options.delay);
  alertify[options.messageType](message);
}
```

In this case you are passing in your `options` property as `Partial<AlertifyOptions>` which means (as stated above) that this value of `options` may not contain **any** of the keys which you are using within the block. So in order for TypeScript to allow you to use any `options` information downstream, you need to prove that the key you are interested is actually present

As you are trying to use `options.messageType` as an index on the `alertify` class/object, TypeScript is saying that **if** this value were to be `undefined`, it would not be possible to be used as an index. i.e. `alertify[undefined]` is invalid syntax.

You need to make sure that `options.messageType` is **not** `undefined` before using it. This can be achieved by simply null checking:

```
message(message: string, options: Partial<AlertifyOptions>) {
  // ...
  if (options.messageType) {
    alertify[options.messageType](message);
  }
}

// or one-liner
message(message: string, options: Partial<AlertifyOptions>) {
  // ...
  options.messageType && alertify[options.messageType](message);
}
```

*Note: I am assuming that the type of `options.messageType` is a union of possible keys on the `alertify` class/object. If this is not the case, the operation would be invalid with or without the null check above*

Comment: Dear friend, thankyou for your work. but my problem that, teh Partial is not working.  because first time when i wrote, it was worked. but next time not..

And i trial you vercion . not solved my problem. thank you agains

Answer (score 0):

> I solved this problem by replacing
> `Partial<AlertifyOptions>` to
> `Required<AlertifyOptions>`.
> Thanks For your attantions..